# ALL unit vectors parallel to a vector

Tags: vectors

I have a question which asks to find ALL unit vectors parallel to a given vector in R3.

I have computed the unit vector using division of the vector by its length. This is a single solution. What is meant by ALL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you count the vector in the opposite direction as parallel as well (which you should) then that's a second solution.

Comment: Besides that I don’t think there’s another solution